# Extraer dato de un texto

Tags: r, regex

Tengo un texto y quiero extraer el gasto certificado

> text <- ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
> Vestibulum ultricies facilisis rhoncus.  Mauris a ullamcorper est,
> eget tempus tortor. Etiam luctus lorem a vehicula lobortis. Proin
> blandit  lectus ut elit feugiat tincidunt. **Gasto certificado:
> 99.190.190,99 €** Gasto del proyecto: 59.999,96 € Etiam sed sapien sit amet nisi venenatis scelerisque sit amet at purus. Praesent in velit
> et purus semper Gasto certificado: 11.122.122,23 € vehicula
> ullamcorper at nisi. Aliquam vehicula sodales elit ac hendrerit. Donec
> dignissim lectus a velit sollicitudin, nec vestibulum sapien suscipit.
> Ut at augue sapien. Nunc in suscipit nulla. Sed gravida accumsan eros
> ut ultrices. Phasellus aliquam  feugiat pretium. Vestibulum .Gasto
> certificado: 77.177.172,27 € Gasto del proyecto: 34.333,33 €efficitur
> aliquam odio venenatis varius. Maecenas semper bibendum nulla sed
> fermentum. Donec at sagittis tortor")

Durante el texto el gasto certificado aparece varias veces. Solo quiero el primero.

He probado con

```
sub(".*Gasto certificado: (\\d.+\\€)", "\\1", text)
```

pero nada.

El resultado esperado es  `99.190.190,99 €`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no confiaría tanto en el formato de los números y simplemente extraería el texto entre `Gasto del proyecto:`  y  `€`, aplicando algo como esto:

```
str_extract(text, "(?<=Gasto del proyecto: ).*?(?= €)")
```

Con `(?<=Gasto del proyecto: )` buscamos lo que le sigue `Gasto del proyecto:` , con `.*?` capturamos la menor cantidad de caracteres (modo "lazy") hasta que `(?= €)` encontremos un caracter de Euros.

La otra forma es hacer básicamente lo mismo pero sin aplicar expresiones regulares que suele ser un enfoque mas "a prueba de balas", la idea es la misma buscamos el primer texto y el símbolo de eros siguientes y recortamos lo del medio:

```
first <- regexpr("Gasto del proyecto: ", text)
pos = first[[1]] + attr(first, "match.length") 

newtext <- substr(text, pos, nchar(text))

first <- regexpr(" €", newtext)
pos = first[[1]] - attr(first, "match.length") + 1 

substr(newtext, 1, pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo de `r` ni idea, pero te puede ayudar con la expresión regular

Esta expresión `([0-9]{1,3}\.?,{0,1})+` buscará los valores numéricos, con separadores de miles y separador decimal

Para encontrar los valores que suceden a la palabra "Gasto certificado" necesitas usar [lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookbehind_assertion) `(?<=)`, en tu caso `(?<=Gasto certificado: )`

Entonces, uniendo los 2 elementos tienes algo como

`(?<=Gasto certificado: )([0-9]{1,3}\.?,{0,1})+ €"`

Demo

```js
const texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ultricies facilisis rhoncus. Mauris a ullamcorper est, eget tempus tortor. Etiam luctus lorem a vehicula lobortis. Proin blandit lectus ut elit feugiat tincidunt. Gasto certificado: 99.190.190,99 € Gasto del proyecto: 59.999,96 € Etiam sed sapien sit amet nisi venenatis scelerisque sit amet at purus. Praesent in velit et purus semper Gasto certificado: 11.122.122,23 € vehicula ullamcorper at nisi. Aliquam vehicula sodales elit ac hendrerit. Donec dignissim lectus a velit sollicitudin, nec vestibulum sapien suscipit. Ut at augue sapien. Nunc in suscipit nulla. Sed gravida accumsan eros ut ultrices. Phasellus aliquam feugiat pretium. Vestibulum .Gasto certificado: 77.177.172,27 € Gasto del proyecto: 34.333,33 €efficitur aliquam odio venenatis varius. Maecenas semper bibendum nulla sed fermentum. Donec at sagittis tortor";

const regex = new RegExp("(?<=Gasto certificado: )([0-9]{1,3}\.?,{0,1})+ €","gi");

console.log(texto.match(regex));
```

Comment: supongo que .* es el equivalente a ?<= De momento no consigo ponerlo en pie en R.

Comment: @DudaR No creo que sea el equivalente.....una expresión regular es igual en todos los lenguajes (por lo menos pasa en todos los que conozco.)